# Best way to write a flexible importer module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A user can import his data from other websites. All he needs to do is type in his username on the foreign website and we'll grab all pictures and save it into his own gallery. Some of the pictures needs to be transformed with rMagick (rotating,watermarking), that depends on the importer (depends on which website the user chooses to import data from)

We are discussing the sexiest and most flexible way to do so. We are using carrierwave, but we will change to paperclip in case it fits us more.

### Importer Structure

The current structure does looks like (its roughly pseudocode)

```
module Importer
  class Website1
    def grab_pictures
    end
  end

  class Website2
    def grab_pictures
    end
  end
end

class ImporterJob        
  def perform(user, type, foreign_username)
    pictures = Importer::type.grab_pictures(foreign_username)

    pictures.each do |picture|
      user.pictures.create picture 
    end
  end
end
```

We struggle with the decision, whats the best return of the importer.

### **Solution1:**

The Importer is **returning an array of strings with URLs** ["http://...", "http://...", "http://..."].
That array we can easily loop and tell carrierwave/paperclip to remote_download the images. After that, we'll run a processor to transform the pictures, if we need to.

```
 def get_picture_urls username
  pictures = []
  page = get_html(username)
  page.scan(/\/p\/\d{4}-\d{2}\/#{username}\/[\w\d]{32}-thumb.jpg/).each do |path|
    pictures << path
  end
  pictures.uniq.collect{|x| "http://www.somewebsite.com/#{x.gsub(/medium|thumb/, "big")}"}
end
```

this actually returns an array ["url_to_image", "url_to_image", "url_to_image"]

Then in the Picture.after_create, we call something to remove the Watermark on that Image.

### **Solution2:**

grab_pictures is downloading each picture to an tempfile and transform it.    it will **return an array of tempfiles** [tempfile, tempfile, tempfile]

code for that is:

```
def read_pictures username
  pictures = []
  page = get_html(username)
  page.scan(/\/p\/\d{4}-\d{2}\/#{username}\/[a-z0-9]{32}-thumb.jpg/).each do |path|
    pictures << path
  end
  pictures.uniq.map { |pic_url| remove_logo(pic_url) }
end

def remove_logo pic_url
    big = Magick::Image.from_blob(@agent.get(pic_url.gsub(/medium.jpg|thumb.jpg/, 'big.jpg')).body).first
    # ... do some transformation and watermarking
    file = Tempfile.new(['tempfile', '.jpg'])
    result.write(file.path)
    file
  end
```

This actually returns an array of [Tempfile, Tempfile, Tempfile]

### Summary

The result will be the same for the user - but internally we are discovering 2 different ways of data handling.

We want to keep logic where it belongs and work as generic as possible.

Can you guys help us with choosing the right way? Longterm we want to have around 15 differnt Importers.

Comment: Excellent question. Let me ask you this for starters. How do you suppose to parallelize your task? As I see it, that's the real question here. It doesn't matter much how you organize your classes. But it matters *a lot* how you organize your workers' pool and processes.

Comment: It will be called by active Job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar situation to this recently - I recommend an array of strings for several reasons:

1. Familiarity: How often are you working with tempfiles?  What about the other developers on your team?  How easy is it to manipulate strings vs manipulating tempfiles?
2. Flexibility: Now you want to just process the picture, but maybe in the future you'll need to keep track of the picture id for each picture from the external site.  That's trivial with an array of strings.  With an array of tempfiles, it's more difficult (just how much depends, but the fact is it will be more difficult).  That of course goes for other as-yet-unknown objectives as well.
3. Speed: It's faster and uses less disk space to process an array of strings than a group of files.  That's perhaps a small issue, but if you get flooded with a lot of photos at the same time, it could be a consideration depending on your environment.

Ultimately, the best thing I can say is start with strings, make a few importers, and then see how it looks and feels.  Pretend you're a project manager or a client - start making strange, potentially unreasonable demands of the data you've collected.  How easy will it be for you to meet those demands with your current implementation?  Would it be easier if you were using tempfiles?

Comment: thanks for your answer. appreciated. i came up witth the same argument as number 2. just return urls, and you can do whatever you want with it, depending on your needs. if your needs are chaning, you just change the processing of the files. if you are having tempfiles and want to change the processing, you need to change the importer (which even sounds stupid imo)

Comment: That's decoupling and is an [important factor of good design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). Among already noted benefits it will give you more simple, maintainable and testable code. Your `Importer::Website<...>` classes should only be concerned with grabbing image urls, passing those down the line for processing.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing this for a similar project, where I have to browse and get information on different websites. On each of those websites I have to reach for same goal by performing roughly the same actions, and they are off-course all structured differently.

The solution is inspired from the basic principles of OOP:

**Main class**: handle the high level operations, handle database operations, handle images operation, manage errors

```
class MainClass

  def import
    # Main method, prepare the download and loop through each images
    log_in
    go_to_images_page
    images = get_list_of_images
    images.each do |url|
      begin
        image_record = download_image url
        transform_image image_record
      rescue
        manage_error
      end
    end
    display_logs
    send_emails
  end

  def download_image(url)
    # Once the specific class returned the images url, this common method
    # Is responsible for downloading and creating database record
    record = Image.new picture: url 
    record.save!
    record
  end  

  def transform_image(record)
    # Transformation is common so this method sits in the main class
    record.watermark!
  end   

  # ... the same for all commom methods (manage_error, display_logs, ...)

end
```

**Specific classes** (one per targeted website) : handle low lovel operations and return data to the main class. The only interraction this class must have is with the website, meaning no database access and no error management as much as possible (don't get stuck by your design ;))

*Note*: In my design I simply inherit from the MainClass, but you can use module inclusion if you prefer.

```
class Target1Site < MainClass
  def log_in
    # Perform specific action in website to log the use in
    visit '/log_in'
    fill_in :user_name, with: ENV['user_name']
    ...
  end

  def go_to_images_page
    # Go to specific url
    visit '/account/gallery'
  end

  def get_list_of_images
    # Use specific css paths
    images = all :css, 'div#image-listing img'
    images.collect{|i| i['src']}
  end

  # ...

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem... I had to import from a xls file, different resource types using:

- The Importer class (`ResourcesGroupsImporter`).
- A base mapper class (`ResourceMapper`) It acts as interface for specific mappers. It has common methods for all resources and **raises `NotImplementedError` encouraging you to implement those methods when you adds a new resource type.**
- One mapper by resource type (`DetentionsPollMapper`, `FrontCycleMapper`). Each one, implements specific logic for an specific resource.

#### Implementation example:

The importer...

```
class ResourcesGroupsImporter
  attr_reader :group
  attr_reader :mappers

  def initialize(_source, _resources_group)
    @group = _resources_group
    @source = _source
    @xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(@source.path, extension: :xlsx)
    @mappers = Resource::RESOURCEABLE_CLASSES.map { |klass| resource_mapper(klass) }
  end

  def import
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      self.mappers.each { |mapper| create_resource(mapper) }
      relate_source_with_group unless self.has_errors?
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if self.has_errors?
    end
  end

  def has_errors?
    !self.mappers.select { |mapper| mapper.has_errors? }.empty?
  end

  private

  def resource_mapper(_class)
    "#{_class}Mapper".constantize.new(@xls, @group)
  end

  def create_resource(_mapper)
    return unless _mapper.resource

    _mapper.load_resource_attributes
    _mapper.resource.complete
    _mapper.resource.force_validation = true

    if _mapper.resource.save
      create_resource_items(_mapper)
    else
      _mapper.load_general_errors
    end
  end

  def create_resource_items(_mapper)
    _mapper.set_items_sheet
    columns = _mapper.get_items_columns

    @xls.each_with_index(columns) do |data, index|
      next if data == columns
      break if data.values.compact.size.zero?
      item = _mapper.build_resource_item(data)
      _mapper.add_detail_errors(index, item.errors.messages) unless item.save
    end
  end

  def relate_source_with_group
    @group.reload
    @group.source = @source
    @group.save!
  end
end
```

The interface...

```
class ResourceMapper
  attr_reader :general_errors
  attr_reader :detailed_errors
  attr_reader :resource

  def initialize(_xls, _resource_group)
    @xls = _xls
    @resource = _resource_group.resourceable_by_class_type(resource_class)
  end

  def resource_class
    raise_implementation_error
  end

  def items_sheet_number
    raise_implementation_error
  end

  def load_resource_attributes
    raise_implementation_error
  end

  def get_items_columns
    raise_implementation_error
  end

  def build_resource_item(_xls_item_data)
    resource_items.build(_xls_item_data)
  end

  def raise_implementation_error
    raise NotImplementedError.new("#{caller[0]} method not implemented on inherited class")
  end

  def has_errors?
    !self.general_errors.nil? || !self.detailed_errors.nil?
  end

  def resource_items
    self.resource.items
  end

  def human_resource_name
    resource_class.model_name.human
  end

  def human_resource_attr(_attr)
    resource_class.human_attribute_name(_attr)
  end

  def human_resource_item_attr(_attr)
    "#{resource_class}Item".constantize.human_attribute_name(_attr)
  end

  def load_general_errors
    @general_errors = self.resource.errors.messages
  end

  def add_detail_errors(_xls_row_idx, _error)
    @detailed_errors ||= []
    @detailed_errors << [ _xls_row_idx+1, _error ]
  end

  def set_items_sheet
    @xls.default_sheet = items_sheet
  end

  def general_sheet
    sheet(0)
  end

  def items_sheet
    sheet(self.items_sheet_number)
  end

  def sheet(_idx)
    @xls.sheets[_idx]
  end

  def general_cell(_col, _row)
    @xls.cell(_col, _row, general_sheet)
  end
end
```

Specific mapper types...

```
class DetentionsPollMapper < ResourceMapper
  def items_sheet_number
    6
  end

  def resource_class
    DetentionsPoll
  end

  def load_resource_attributes
    self.resource.crew = general_cell("N", 3)
    self.resource.supervisor = general_cell("N", 4)
  end

  def get_items_columns
    {
      issue: "Problema identificado",
      creation_date: "Fecha",
      workers_count: "N° Trabajadores esperando",
      detention_hours_string: "HH Detención",
      lost_hours: "HH perdidas",
      observations: "Observación"
    }
  end

  def build_resource_item(_xls_item_data)
    activity = self.resource.activity_by_name(_xls_item_data[:issue])

    data = {
      creation_date: _xls_item_data[:creation_date],
      workers_count: _xls_item_data[:workers_count],
      detention_hours_string: _xls_item_data[:detention_hours_string],
      lost_hours: _xls_item_data[:lost_hours],
      observations: _xls_item_data[:observations],
      activity_id: !!activity ? activity.id : nil
    }

    resource_items.build(data)
  end
end

class FrontCycleMapper < ResourceMapper
  def items_sheet_number
    8
  end

  def resource_class
    FrontCycle
  end

  def load_resource_attributes
    self.resource.front = general_cell("S", 3)
  end

  def get_items_columns
    {
      task: "Tarea",
      start_time_string: "Hora",
      task_type: "Tipo de Tarea",
      description: "Descripción"
    }
  end

  def build_resource_item(_xls_item_data)
    activity = self.resource.activity_by_name_and_category(
      _xls_item_data[:task], _xls_item_data[:task_type])

    data = {
      description: _xls_item_data[:description],
      start_time_string: _xls_item_data[:start_time_string],
      activity_id: !!activity ? activity.id : nil
    }

    resource_items.build(data)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A helper have to provide a way to access pict as you prefer.

However saving "http://...", "http://...", "http://..." this kind of strings, is a lack of security.

I 'd preferd hash like this: domain_name = {"name_on_url.jpg" =>path_on_disk, ...}

To ensure flexibility of access.

Comment: where is that a lack of security? we wrote an importer for website1.com and that is returning [/path/file.jpg, /path/file.jpg] so the last line of code is return pictures.collect{|x| "http://www.website1.com/" + x }

Comment: i think i've taked "http://" to literally , and the less you duplicate data the less you read data

Comment: that is the other approach, that grabs the pcitures as tempfiles and directly transform those http://pastie.org/10367203

Comment: there is some imagehost  were you can delegate transform if you want go faster:

Comment: no we need to control it by ourself. actually we are removing watermarks

Comment: Treatment of Image is the heaviest thing you l'have to batch && ruby is better with hashes (flex , and perf).